# How to use unicode in perl CGI param

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script accepting unicode characters as one of the params.
The url is of the form

```
.../worker.pl?text="some_unicode_chars"&...
```

In the perl script, I pass the $text variable to a shell script:

```
system "a.sh \"$text\" out_put_file";
```

If I hardcode the text in the perl script, it works well. However, the output makes no sense when $text is got from web using CGI.

```
my $q = CGI->new;  
my $text = $q->param('text');
```

I suspect it's the encoding caused the problem. uft-8 caused me so many troubles. Anyone please help me？

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this will help. From [Perl Programming/Unicode UTF-8](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_Programming/Unicode_UTF-8#Input_-_Web_Forms):

> By default, [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) does not decode your form parameters. You can use
>   the `-utf8` pragma, which will treat (and decode) all parameters as
>   UTF-8 strings, but this will fail if you have any binary file upload
>   fields. A better solution involves overriding the param method:
>   *(example follows)*

**[Wrong - see Correction]** Here's [documentation for the `utf-8` pragma](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/lib/utf8.pm). Since uploading binary data does not appear to be a concern for you, use of the `utf-8` pragma appears to be the most straightforward approach.

**Correction:** Per the comment from @Slaven, do not confuse the general Perl `utf8` pragma with the [`-utf-8` pragma](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.64/lib/CGI.pm#PRAGMAS) that has been defined for use with `CGI.pm`:

> -utf8
>
> This makes CGI.pm treat all parameters as UTF-8 strings. Use this with
>   care, as it will interfere with the processing of binary uploads. It
>   is better to manually select which fields are expected to return utf-8
>   strings and convert them using code like this:

```perl
use Encode;
my $arg = decode utf8=>param('foo');
```

**Follow Up:** duleshi, you ask: *But I still don't understand the differnce between decode in Encode and utf8::decode. How do the Encode and utf8 modules differ?*

From the documentation for the [utf8 pragma](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/lib/utf8.pm):

> **Note that this function does not handle arbitrary encodings.** Therefore
>   Encode is recommended for the general purposes; see also [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode).

Put another way, the `Encode` module works with ***many*** different encodings (including UTF-8), whereas the `utf8` functions work ***only*** with the UTF-8 encoding.

Here is a Perl program that demonstrates the equivalence of the two approaches to encoding and decoding UTF-8. (Also see the [live demo](http://ideone.com/fJQcxa).)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;  # allows 'ñ' to appear in the source code

use Encode;

my $word = "Español";  # the 'ñ' is permitted because of the 'use utf8' pragma

# Convert the string to its UTF-8 equivalent.
my $utf8_word = Encode::encode("UTF-8", $word);

# Use 'utf8::decode' to convert the string back to internal form.
my $word_again_via_utf8 = $utf8_word;
utf8::decode($word_again_via_utf8);  # converts in-place

# Use 'Encode::decode' to convert the string back to internal form.
my $word_again_via_Encode = Encode::decode("UTF-8", $utf8_word);

# Do the two conversion methods produce the same result?
# Prints 'Yes'.
print $word_again_via_utf8 eq $word_again_via_Encode ? "Yes\n" : "No\n";

# Do we get back the original internal string after converting both ways?
# Prints 'Yes'.
print $word eq $word_again_via_Encode ? "Yes\n" : "No\n";
```

Comment: The utf-8 pragma documentation says: "Do not use this pragma for anything else than telling Perl that your script is written in UTF-8.". So this is not needed here.

Comment: I think the real culprit maybe the permission settings, which is the cause of many errors for CGI newcomers like me. It's weekend so I haven't tested it. Anyway, your answer is very helpful. Thanks! But I still don't understand the differnce between decode in Encode and utf8::decode. How do the Encode and utf8 modules differ?

Comment: duleshi - Please see the additional explanation I added following **Follow Up**.

Comment: It doesn't work. my $text = decode utf8=>$q->param('text');  open D, '>', 'dd.txt';  print D $text;  close D;  The content in dd.txt is garbled.

Comment: duleshi - You didn't open your file and indicate a UTF-8 encoding. Try:  `open D, '>:utf8', 'dd.txt';` For more see: [Unicode I/O](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html#Unicode-I/O). Since file I/O extends beyond your original question, consider asking another question if you are still having difficulty. (Or better, try first finding the answer on SO.)

Comment: I have set the -utf8 flag for CGI and my file uploads seem to be working fine still. Am I misunderstanding the documentation? Weren't binary uploads (I tried a jpeg) supposed to break with this flag on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing UTF-8 data around in the parameters list, then you definitely want to be URI encoding them using the [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Escape.pm) module. This will convert any extended characters to percent values which as easily printable and readable. On the receiving end you will then need to URI *decode* them before continuing.

Comment: That's actually what we do now. But that means another layer is needed. I'd prefer the way to enter unicode characters directly into the address bar of a browser.

Comment: It's another layer, but the correct layer as stated in the RFC (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2). URI encoding covers more than just extended characters, but reserved ones as well. For examples, spaces and forward slashes.